# Using Namespace visibility in header

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I am working on a c++ library which is split up into multiple namespaces. Since I am trying to avoid the "using" directive in header files I am forced to do the alternative "namespace::class" for variables, returns and parameters. As you can imagine this could get messy. So, I tried putting the using statement inside a namespace decloration (see below) and that seemed to do the trick, It doesn't appear to be visible in files including this file.

```
namespace Project
{
    namespace Utility { class A; }

namespace System
{
    using Utility::A;

    class B
    {
        A *a;   // instead of Utility::A *a
    };
}
}
```

My question is, would it be okay to do this instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// your header

namespace Project
{
    namespace Utility { class A; }

namespace System
{
    using Utility::A;

    class B
    {
        A *a;   // instead of Utility::A *a
    };
}
}

// end your header

class A {};

int main()
{
    using namespace Project::System;
    A a;
}

test.cpp:25:5: error: reference to 'A' is ambiguous
    A a;
    ^
test.cpp:20:7: note: candidate found by name lookup is 'A'
class A {};
      ^
test.cpp:9:20: note: candidate found by name lookup is 'Project::System::A'
    using Utility::A;
                   ^
1 error generated.
```

Comment: This also occurs e.g. for `using namespace std` and defining something called `cout` at global scope. I.e. it is not directly related to the OP's question. But it's worth being aware of (as a general problem), so I upvoted.

Comment: The difference is that cout is known to be defined in namespace std.  A is *not* known to be defined in namespace Project::System.  The client gets Project::System::A by surprise (unless documented otherwise).

Answer (score 1):

It is less bad, if nothing else.

On the other hand, I don't think it is "messy" to spell out the full names when you use them. To me, that just adds clarity to the code.

Comment: From a user perspective yes, but from a library perspective it no longer allows me to neatly align function signatures making it look a little bit messy.

Answer (score 0):

Namespaces can be overused as anything else. and if your code become messy because of namespaces it's a good indication that you probably overuse them.

If you use namespaces to separate independent domains you shouldn't specify them explicitly too often.